# Video Streaming between two android devices

Tags: android

I need help about that how can I do real time video streaming between two android devices,please give me any sample code or any link which it will helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of examples how you can take data from camera and transport it somewhere: https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera

Actually you can do it by Wi-Fi or bluetooth.